# ASP.NET Masterpage CSS Background Image Borders

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, master-pages

For my masterpage, I embedded an image on HTML DIV. Background image did appear, but with 4 white border-like surrounding my image, where I didn't apply any.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >

    <div style="border-width: thin; border-style: inset; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; top: 89px; left: 169px; position: absolute; height: 570px; width: 777px; background-color: #FFFFFF; z-index: auto;">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 757px; background-image: url('<%= imgPath %>'); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-attachment: fixed; position: static;">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: However, even removing the first div doesn't solve it.

Comment: Can you use **firebug** and check what are the styles applied to the image containing div ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<body style="border: 0px none; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
```